# Would it be possible to generate a memorized wallet address by using a batch of phone numbers?

Tags: wallet, address

I was wondering if I was able to generate a bitcoin wallet by using a bunch of phone numbers i remember. I'm sure everyone can recall at least 5 or 10 phone numbers by memory. So in theory I can reference the wallet by just remembering the people thats associated with it. Say my wallet would consist of: john, sam, eva, jesse, and ben. but it would be referenced as phone numbers and in turn gets converted to a bitcoin wallet address.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the phone numbers as a passphrase for a [Brain Wallet](https://brainwallet.org).